# Independent width in a WPF Grid

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, grid

I have a grid with 2 rows and 2 columns in WPF. I would like that the column widths are independent for each row. I tried "auto", but no success. Here is a picture in order to explain:

[image]

How can I accomplish this using grid?

Comment: What do you mean by "columns widht are independants"? and what you want?

Comment: Try setting your column span property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you must use a grid layout, then you have a couple of options:

Option 1: Make each row a single column and then nest a grid in each row you would like independent columns:

**XAML**

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <TextBlock Text="AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA" />

    <Grid Grid.Row="1">
      <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
      </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

      <TextBlock Text="BBBBBBB"">
      <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="CCCCCCC" />
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Option 2: Make use of ColumnSpan in the rows:

**XAML**

```
<Grid>
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition />
    <RowDefinition />
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>

  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition />
    <ColumnDefinition />
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

      <TextBlock Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Text="AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA" />
      <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text="BBBBBBB"">
      <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="CCCCCCC" />
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

*These were typed without an editor and may need a bit of tweaking.

Answer (score 0):

Two grids?

```
<StackPanel Width="277">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Text="AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"/>            
    </Grid>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Text="BBBBBBB" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"/>
        <TextBlock Text="CCCCCCC" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"/>
    </Grid>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: If using a StackPanel for the layout, there is no need for the first grid since there is only a single TextBlock element within the grid. Further, the first grid has unnecessary columns; the entire row and column definition could be deleted all together which would leave just a TextBlock nested inside a Grid. See my answer with two different layouts with a single grid.

Comment: @MetroSmurf Yeah fair enough, I am assuming he does have some more to put in the second column on the first grid though. If he want's totally independant widths for his rows, this isn't possible even with rowspans.