# Manage columnspan in a grid

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-7, xaml

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Independants width in a WPF Grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14185191/independants-width-in-a-wpf-grid)

I would like to dispay 3 textBlocks on a grid (2 x 2)

I need to use columnspan but i can't do it right.

What i have :

[image]

What i want :

[image]

I tried several manipulation.

Here is my code :

```
<Grid Margin="20" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
 <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition />
    <RowDefinition />
 </Grid.RowDefinitions>

 <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
 </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
 <TextBlock  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Margin="0,0,10,0" x:Name="TxtBox_cCodeTiers" Text="{Binding m_strCode}" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="22" />
 <TextBlock  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Margin="0,0,10,0" x:Name="TxtBox_cNomTiers" Text="{Binding m_strNom}"   FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="22" />
 <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Margin="0,0,10,0" x:Name="TxtBox_cCPostal" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding m_strFonction}" />
</Grid>
```

I know i need to use ColumnSpan but i tried and no result :(

Anyone could

Comment: This looks nearly identical to the [question you asked 2 weeks ago](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14185191/) and accepted the answer. What is different about this question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try adding `Grid.ColumnSpan` in the last `TextBlock` :

```
<TextBlock  Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Margin="0,0,10,0" x:Name="TxtBox_cCPostal" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding m_strFonction}" />
```

Comment: You don't have to remove the `Grid.Column="0"`.